How to detect movement of an item in a SliverReorderableList while the draggable item is still in overlay in Flutter?
I'm currently using a SliverReorderableList in my Flutter project to display a list of items. I need to detect when an item in the list has moved, even while the draggable item is still in overlay (not yet dropped) and the onReorder callback is not triggered. Here's the code snippet I'm working with:
SliverReorderableList(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ReorderableDelayedDragStartListener(
    key: ValueKey<String>(state.mergeCities[index].name),
    index: index,
    child: CityCard(
      isSelected: index == 0 && state.selectedCity != null,
      city: state.mergeCities[index],
    ),
  ),
  itemCount: state.mergeCities.length,
  onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
),

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?
